# Excel: How to find name in sheet and mark "yes" on another column

Tags: excel

Let's say I have a excel sheet like this one below just with many more names
[image]

and I have another list where I have a certain number of names. How do I make a code so that if I input in the names from the other sheet, and if it matches 70% 
(or 100% if that is not possible) with the names on the first sheet, then a "yes" will be printed on column D.

like let's say I want to find "John" and "Jerry" on the list, and I put it in the formula, then only a "yes" will be marked after "John" since the latter name is not in the list?

Comment: For a fuzzy match this might help:  [Fuzzy Matching](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/195635-fuzzy-matching-new-version-plus-explanation.html).  For a 100% matching have a look at [FIND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) - there's plenty of examples on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
IF(IFERROR(MATCH(A2,$H$2:$H$5,0)>0,FALSE),"Yes","No")
```

See:
[image]

The list in column H can be on another sheet, just drag down to check cells in col A.

Comment: so select all values in a and then enter formula and then press cntrl enter?

Comment: It’s not an array formula, try it.

Comment: Ok just tried it but then I could only go one box each time. Also is it possible to get a "yes" for a 70% match?

Comment: 3 letters in order =75%

Comment: You could use left()... ie left(A2,3) and then think about the list in col H or duplicate it and have two tests...

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

- Assuming *"John"* is in cell `Aé`
- Assuming your list is on `Sheet2`, column `A`
- Using `,` as delimiter

  `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,0)),"","yes")`